# Android: Change color of 1 listview entry applies on every 9th

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm writing a little android application. 
I have got a problem with a listview.
When an entry is clicked, the state of the datastructure should be marked as selected or not selected. In the datastructure everything is fine, but the selection should be visualised by changeing the backgroundcolor of the entry. 
So far so good, but after a click the correct element change its color, but also **every 9th** element (entry 0 clicked -> changed color, but also entry 8, entry 16 and so on)in the listview but i have no idea why.

Question: Why does not only the clicked entry changed Color.?

Here my getView code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if (listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

    final User currentUser = userList.get(position);

    TextView username = listItem.findViewById(R.id.lv_username);
    String state = "disabled";
    if(currentUser.getSelected()) state = "enabled";
    username.setText(currentUser.getUsername() + " - " + state);
    listItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentUser.setSelected(!currentUser.getSelected());
            if (currentUser.getSelected()) {
                Log.d("onClick in Adapter", "selected");
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("onClick in Adapter", "not selected");
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return listItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the way the recyclingview works, since a previously non-visible view is being used, all state is kept, so when reusing it will be already colored (note that if you click it will not become transparent, but clicking twice will cause the data structure is intact).

The solution is to always reapply the state to a view about to become visible.

```
if (listItem == null)
    listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
listItem.setBackgroundColor(currentUser.getSelected() ? Color.WHITE : Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this, inside getview get the position check if it equals 9th, then change background color for that row.

```
if (position==9){
            convertView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: I could not understand the question.. but after reading your answer, I don't understand it doubly !

Comment: he wants to change color of 9th row inside listview.

Comment: i am just giving him general idea of how he can achieve it. by getting position and doing desired action